# Texmaker: change interface font

Tags: fonts, texmaker, changes, interfaces

I have just installed the macOS Catalina on my Mac and it somehow changed the font interface of Texmaker (I don't use the latest version). I now have a weird cursive font that I really do not like and that doesn't allow every character so I sometimes have blocks instead of letters.

I've managed to change the font of where I type and code in the font I previously had but the interface itself I can't find where to change it (see pic)

Does anyone know how to do that? I know it doesn't look like much but I really use the structure side and shortcuts and shortcuts section, chapter, etc. And it's all written in that font as well, making it hard to read.

Thank you so much in advance :)[image]

Comment: In the Editor button?

Comment: I tried that but it only changes where you actually type and code things, not the interface and menu font itself

Comment: Is just this application affected?